# why doesn't the dynamically made controlgroup gets removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Being new to Jquery & its Mobile version i am not able to figure out the issue :

I am trying to load Dynamic ControlGroups which somehow is not working for me .

Here is a small script http://jsfiddle.net/NVbjr/15/
which i am working with .

The script works totally fine for normal control groups but when my control groups are generated dynamically the same code does not work .

I have tried `trigger("create")` ,like `$("#resultObjects").trigger("create");` 
that didn't work for me and moreover it also removed the applied styles on my selector .

What might be the reason ? and necessary solution ?

**Edit :  Here's something which i tried after Omar's suggestion , but no result . http://jsfiddle.net/2rLq00rf/9/**

Thanks!

Comment: which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set ***data-role*** attributes, you should to set them if you want that jquery mobile apply styles

e.g.

```
<a href='#' data-role='button'>Button</a>
```

and afterwards you can call `.trigger('create')`

Comment: @Omar why down vote ? in JS fiddle 1.1.1 is referenced

Comment: `<a class="ui-btn ui-btn-b  ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-mini">Btn 2</a>` = jQM 1.4. Solution: controlgroup should be refreshed after deleting an element. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2rLq00rf/

Comment: @Motoo : if i am correct including the class="ui-btn" says that the data-role="button"

Comment: @Omar : thanks for the answer , but it doesn't seem to work with the dynamically appended controlgroup . check my edit please !

Comment: @thinkinbee you're still not appending _controlgroup_ correctly, plus, dragging event should be attached to buttons within _controlgroup_ http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2rLq00rf/

Comment: @Omar : My bad . But still in your fiddle if you observe the "notext button" is not getting removed,since i am expecting the whole controlgroup to be removed not just one button in it . what might be the reason ?

Comment: @thinkinbee I'm removing the button only. If you want to remove the whole controlgroup the btn belongs to `delClass.closest(".ui-controlgroup").remove()`.

Comment: @Omar : thanks Omar. works ! I Also added the drag functionality to the whole controlgroup instead of just the button . http://jsfiddle.net/thinkinbee/2rLq00rf/14/ .

Also it would be nice if you put your comment as an answer .